# synchronise rows of all postgres db tables using primary/foreign keys

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have a postgres database with 30 tables. The main table "general_data" has a column "building_code", which all the other tables use as foreign key.
What I would need is to synchronise the "building_code" columns in all tables, meaning if a row is added in "general_data" a row is created in ALL tables with the the same value in "building_code" (the other columns remain empty).

Is there an SQL function that does that?

Comment: You would need to create a trigger for that. But what would you put into the `NOT NULL` columns of those other table during insert?

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I will look into it. I am developing a web application which dynamically accesses the tables in the db. The values for the columns other than "building code" will be inserted later by the users of the webapp and therefore have to remain empty for now. They are mainly "text", "integer" and "real". I have no experience with trigger functions, any best practice ideas how to handle the issue? thnx